# Java - Better way then using Ifs and repeating functions - DateRelated

Tags: function, date, if-statement, switch-statement, contains

I created a function to check my Date string for what month it contains so I can use it for multiple date formats. But I'm using a lot of *ifs* and repeating the .contains function. Is there a better way of doing this?

Also related my dates are in the format Weekday(String), Month(String) day(int- XX), Year(Int - XXXX). e.g. Sunday, June 27, 1965. I've had no luck so far with the built in functions.

```
    public static int CheckMonth(String s){
    String month = s.toLowerCase();

    if(month.contains("january")){return 1;}
    else if(month.contains("febuary")){return 2;}
    else if(month.contains("march")){return 3;}
    else if(month.contains("april")){return 4;}
    else if(month.contains("may")){return 5;}
    else if(month.contains("june")){return 6;}
    else if(month.contains("july")){return 7;}
    else if(month.contains("august")){return 8;}
    else if(month.contains("september")){return 9;}
    else if(month.contains("october")){return 10;}
    else if(month.contains("november")){return 11;}
    else if(month.contains("december")){return 12;}
    else {return -1;}       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use a loop. For example,

```
// 'lookup'
static String[] monthNames = {"january", .., "december"};

// in method
for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
   if (monthName.contains(monthNames[i])) {
      return i + 1; // because 0..11 indices in array
   }
}
// do something if no matching month was found
```

Although if trying to "NLP" a date, I'm sure there are existing libraries ..

Comment: Yeah there are but I've had no luck with them so far. This is neater anyway. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do, using an enum to store the text and the number could be used. For example:

```
public enum Month {
    JANUARY("january", 1), FEBRUARY("february", 2) ... DECEMBER("december", 12);

    private final String string;
    private final int number;

    private Month(String string, int number) {
        this.string = string;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getMonthNumber(String string) {
        for(Month month : Month.values()) {
            if(string.contains(this.string))
                return month.number
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```